# can i replace regExp with another regExp?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
 var str='The_Andy_Griffith_Show'; // string to perform replace on
 var regExp1=/\s|[A-Z]/g;
 var regExp2=/[^A-Z]/g;            // regular expression
 var str2 =str.replace(regExp2,regExp1); 
 // expected output: The_ Andy_ Griffith_ Show
```

I want to replace all the first capital letters of a string with a space and that same letter, and if that's not possible is there a workaround?

Comment: Is there a space before `The` in the expected output?

Comment: Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace **no**. You can use either string or function - RegExp is an object

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a space before *any* captial letter, it is enough to use

```js
var str='The_Andy_Griffith_Show';
str = str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, ' $&')
console.log(str); // => "  The_ Andy_ Griffith_ Show"
```

Here, `/[A-Z]/g` matches all ASCII uppercase letters and `$&` is a backreference to the whole match value.

If you want to only add a space before the first capital letter in a word, you need to use capturing groups and backreferences to thier values in the replacement pattern:

```js
var str='The_Andy_Griffith_Show'; // string to perform replace on
str = str.replace(/(^|[^A-Z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
console.log(str); // => "  The_ Andy_ Griffith_ Show"
```

Remove `^|` if you do not want to add space before a capital letter at the string start (i.e. use `/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/g`).

Answer (score 0):

To add space to all occurrences of capital letters:

```js
var str = 'The_Andy_Griffith_Show',
    str2 = str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => ` ${letter}`);
    
console.log(str2);
```

Notice that if you want no to add space to the first letter occurrence, just use the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/(?!^)[A-Z]/g`.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative to the other answers.
To get that expected result you could just match the non-uppercases that are followed by an uppercase character, then replace them with the match `$&` and a space.

For example:

```js
var str='The_Andy_Griffith_Show';
str = str.replace(/[^A-Z](?=[A-Z])/g, '$& ')
console.log(str);
```

Or simply match those uppercases followed by an uppercase character.

```js
var str='The_Andy_Griffith_Show';
str = str.replace(/[_](?=[A-Z])/g, '$& ')
console.log(str);
```